# Understand abrupt jumps at the end of the score history of h2o deeplearning models

Tags: r, neural-networks, h2o

I train deep learning models on the fashion MNIST dataset using H2O with the R interface. My score history often looks strange: the end is jumping up or down as two different values are reported for the last epoch.

Here is an example:
[image]

How could the training RMSE be 0.38416 and also 0.39117 at the same time after 10 epochs? (Sometimes I get even more expressed differences where the last value is almost double of the previous one.) The same is true for other metrics as well. See the plot for the classification error:
[image]

Could you please explain how rows 11 and 12 differ?

Here is the reproducible code (you can download the data from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zalando-research/fashionmnist?select=fashion-mnist_train.csv):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(h2o)

h2o.init()

fmnist_data <- read_csv("fashion-mnist_train.csv")

# standardization
fmnist_data <- mutate(fmnist_data, 
    label = as.factor(label),
    across(-label, ~./255)
)

# data splitting
data_split <- h2o.splitFrame(as.h2o(fmnist_data), ratios = 0.05, seed = 1234)
fmnist_train <- data_split[[1]]
fmnist_holdout <- data_split[[2]]

# training
dl_fit <- h2o.deeplearning(
    x = 2:785,
    y = "label",
    hidden = c(8, 8),
    training_frame = fmnist_train,
    validation_frame = fmnist_holdout,
    seed = 12345,
    reproducible = TRUE
)
plot(dl_fit, metric = "classification_error")
h2o.scoreHistory(dl_fit)
```

Comment: Another intriguing question is why it is optimizing the RMSE (root mean squared error?) for a classification problem.

Comment: It is just part of the whole scoring history table that contains multiple measures. The model optimizes for cross-entropy.

Comment: Then problem solved! The RMSE column is irrelevant to either the training or the evaluation as you are interested in the classification error. (The question of how RMSE is computed for a multi-class classification problem remains open...)

Comment: The jump can be observed in each metric. Please note that I plotted the classification error where the jump can also be observed.

Comment: The main question is how we can observe two different values for seemingly the same point of the training process. I consulted the h2o documentation but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what is happening is that the training does 10 epochs of training, and then chooses the epoch with the lowest *validation* score as the model to use.
Which is at epoch 9 in the example you give.

So the final line of the scoring history just repeats the metrics for the best version of the model it chose. I.e. it is saying "this is the score of the best model after 10 epochs".

Comment: Thanks Darren. That makes sense. And the choice is based on the validation set using the logloss metric by default (as this is used for early stopping for classification problems).